# PowerShell: network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, powershell

On my Skype For Business Server, when I run the following command, my Queue get's changed as it should:

```
Set-CsRgsQueue -Instance $queue
```

On my linked server however (one hop away from the Lync server), i get the following error:

> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Set-CsRgsQueue : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the 
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I am however able to set up ODBC to the remote server (+ opened FW 1433 port, restarted the service ,....)

Where could my problem be?

EDIT:

My scriptblock looks like:

```
import-module Lync 
$queue = Get-CsRgsQueue -Name $toChange
$action = New-CsRgsCallAction -Action TransferToPSTN -Uri $forwarduri -QueueID $queue.Identity
$queue.OverflowAction = $action
$queue.OverflowThreshold = 0
Set-CsRgsQueue -Instance $queue
```

If i'm not able to solve the issue, how could I implement `invoke-command` as this works on the server itself?

I tried by doing:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SQLSERVER -ScriptBlock {Set-CsRgsQueue -Instance $queue}
```

but this throws:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Instance'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
```

Comment: could you connect via SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: this isn't installed and i dont want to install it on top of a skype for business installation

Comment: Are you able to connect to it using `New-PSSession` and `Enter-PSSession`?

Comment: yes i'm able to @trebleCode

Comment: Once entering the PSSession are you able to run the commands regularly on that system? Or is using `Invoke-Command` your primary need?

Comment: yes i'm able to @trebleCode but my script is ran on the local terminal server and retrieves its variables to a GUI so i need to find a workaround

Comment: Are you able to use the `using` scope, since the problem is `$queue` is otherwise a null variable in the scriptblock's scope- `Invoke-Command -ComputerName SQLSERVER -Scriptblock {Set-CsRgsQueue -Instance $using:queue}`?  Some other approaches as well - https://lazywinadmin.com/2017/03/ScriptBlockObject.html#creating-your-own-scriptblock